# Get disk free space using ipmi from esxi

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, snmp, ipmi, ipmitool

I want to get disk status of esxi server using ipmi.
I can not find the right command to get this information:

```
/usr/sbin/ipmitool -I lan -H 192.168.x.x -U xxx -P xxx -S /tmp/ipmi-sdr-cache
```

Which commands shoud i add to get information about disk space, free space ... ?

Comment: Maybe you could try with SNMP.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. IPMI is working below the operating system and offers functionality to monitor the physical status of your hardware (e.g. voltages, temps, fan speed, disk fail status).

Free disk space is a logical function of the running operating system and can't be reported by IPMI. You would need to use something like SNMP, a Nagios plugin or something similar for this.

Comment: Where can i find the list of OID for ESXI, to find the disk space and free space ?,

Comment: @Abdou [Simple Google search](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1013445)